# I want to read the hexadecimal number of a binary file sequentially by 6 bytes

Tags: python, hex, binascii

```
import binascii
import sys
from os.path import getsize

target = './'+sys.argv[1]

with open(target,'rb+') as f:
    file_size = getsize(target)
    string1 = f.read(6)
    
    print("Size : %d"%file_size)
    print (binascii.b2a_hex(string1))
```

I have a file that is 1220 bytes in size.
ignore the first 20 bytes
I want to output 6 bytes from the 21st byte.

for example, 
There is hex data of 
00 00 00 00 00 ... 00 00 00 ( 20bytes 0x00  ) AA BB CC DD EE FF
GG HH II JJ KK LL
MM ...

My expected Output : 
AA BB CC DD EE FF
GG HH II JJ KK LL
MM....
..
..
I want to load and output 6 bytes one by one as shown.

I wrote code to get the file size for this.
But I can't quite figure out what to do after that.
So I ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, your code reads the first 6 bytes. To skip 20 bytes before the read you can use the `seek()` method [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek). To display the hexadecimal values seperated by a space you can use the `bytes.hex` function [[2]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex). Putting all together you could go with something like:

```
import binascii
import sys
from os.path import getsize

target = './'+sys.argv[1]

with open(target,'rb+') as f:
    file_size = getsize(target)
    
    # read 6 bytes from position 20
    f.seek(20)
    string1 = f.read(6)

    print("Size : %d"%file_size)
    print (string1.hex(' ',1))
```

Comment: How can I output 6 bytes sequentially to the end of the file?

Comment: just use `f.seek(-6, SEEK_END)` as described in the second link